# Customizing set intersection in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have read all the posts about how to customize set intersection in Python and i was trying the concept in my laptop, when i just cannot figure out why this does not work as expected. Here is my code :

```
class ComparableWord:
    def __init__(self, word: str):
        self.word = word

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.word)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("Finally ....")
        return self.word.lower() == other.word.lower()


first = [ComparableWord(word) for word in ["Jack", "Mike", "John", "Paul"]]
second = [ComparableWord(word) for word in ["jack", "Leo", "paul"]]

print("Intersection...")

for word in set(first).intersection(set(second)):
    print(word.word)

print("Union..")

for w in set(first).union(set(second)):
    print(w.word)
```

The output it gives is as follows :

```
Intersection...
Union..
Mike
jack
Jack
John
paul
Leo
Paul
```

Can someone please point out what is going wrong. Also as a side request can someone also tell me how to type annotate the `other` variable in the method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    print("Finally ....")
    return self.word.lower() == other.word.lower()
```

Many thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Your `__hash__` and `__eq__` are incompatible with each other. Your `__hash__` is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you . Can you please tell me what us the rule here ?

Comment: If `x == y`, then you have to have `hash(x) == hash(y)`.